# Get the Text inside the element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:
           justify;line-height:normal">
First Text 

<span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;
            font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;">
Second Text</span>

</p>
```

This is my code, how to get the content inside the paragraph tag. [The tag may change to div or ul]. I need all the content inside the paragraph tag by javascript.

The output should be :

First Text Second Text

Sorry I am new to javascript, searched but cant find answer for this relevant problem. Thanks

Comment: `$('p').text();` Have you event tried it.

Comment: @Franky no mention of jquery in the question

Comment: for javascript `var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a tag, you can get the element with a selector and use `innerHTML` to get the value. like this:

`<p>hi there</p>`

`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);`

**n.b.** in the code above it's selecting by tag name, so it returns an array of matching elements

So in your example, using `.innerHTML` with give you the `P` tags content, including any html tags etc.

if you want just the content, you can use `.textContent`

`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent);`
This **wont** give you the inner html tags

**n.b.** there is also the `innerText` method, However this isnt supported accross browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change according to the tag you need, but basically this will do the trick:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swjuq1kb/)

Answer (score 0):

InnerText should be a good solution.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText);
```

```html
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:
           justify;line-height:normal">
First Text 

<span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;
            font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;">
Second Text</span>

</p>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `innerText` isn't fully supported across browsers