# Manipulate javascript variable[HTML] to diplay only Text

Tags: javascript

This is my code.

```
var Text = "First:<div>Second<span> Text</span></div><p>Third <span>Text</span></p><div>Forth.</div>";
```

I need to manipulate the variable and display only the text.

The output should be like this :

```
First :
Second Text
Third Text
Forth
```

It should leave a line only when it finds a block element. As I am new to javascript, I can only do this when the html is in the DOM. I need to dynamically do this in the javascript variable.

Edit : 1

The answer suggested by you is working. But its not working for this variable.

```
var text = '<p class="MsoListParagraph" style="margin-left:.25in;text-align:justify;
text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo2"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="font-size: 10pt;">3.<span style="font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><!--[endif]--><span lang="EN-IN" style="font-size: 10pt;">Text&nbsp;<b>Text</b>&nbsp;Text.</span><span style="font-size: 10pt;"><o:p></o:p></span></p>';
```

Its showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in console

Give me some solution for this please.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: @atmd I have raised a question before and you have answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487516/get-the-text-inside-the-element?noredirect=1#comment47134674_29487516. As I am new to javascript, I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my attempt solves your problem.
Here is the link

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshay/prsrrjkm/)

```
 var Text = "First:<div>Second<span> Text</span></div><p>Third <span>Text</span></p><div>Forth.</div>";
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML=Text;
```

Edit: It was the double quotes issue in your code.

[JSfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshay/prsrrjkm/1/)

Comment: Changed the question. Please look in to it.

Comment: @user3635719 changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

Injecting that string into the dom using `innerHTML` should give you the output you want, as the text will be converted to html elements. (something `innterText` wont give you).

[here's a jsfiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qfnfmwc/)

```
var Text = "First:<div>Second<span> ETC . . .";

document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = Text;
```

Comment: i think i posted the same thing

Comment: Changed the question. Please look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Put it as innerHTML in some element (if I get understood what you wana do):

```js
function writeText(){
  document.getElementById("ph").innerHTML = "First:<div>Second<span> Text</span></div><p>Third <span>Text</span></p><div>Forth.</div>";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="writeText()" >write it</button>
    <div id="ph"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```